# Conditionally build GraphQL query in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to build a Gatsby page that needs data from two sources (both rest APIs). The first one can be easily filtered, so I only get the data I want.

Let's say this is the GraphQL query for source1:

```
query {
  users{
    name
    reference
  }
}
```

Now, I need to get a bunch of data from source2 (a rest API), and link it with the one in source 1 by the field reference

```
query {
    entity {
        reference,
        field1,
        field2
    }
}
```

I could just build both queries, and then filter, *but*...

- Query from source 1 is filtered, so it will only return a subset of the data, but I can only filter source 2 saying, somehow, only return values where reference matches to values already fetched from source 1. And I can't just fetch all *entities* data from source2 and filter it client side because the result would be **huge**, and superslow

I *think* I'd be able to do that using some type of resolver associated with the type of *reference* in source 1. Is that true? In that case, any example on how to do that?

If resolvers are not the way to go, how could I do it?